# How can I retrieve the hostname from an IP address using Dart?

Tags: flutter, flutter-network

I have a Flutter app that retrieves IP addresses on the network, and I need to obtain the name of a host within the network using the IP address, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use internet address from dart Io
await InternetAddress("your ip address").reverse();
This line returns an Internet address future that has a parameter host.
I hope this answer your question.

Comment: i have this error on your code: <asynchronous suspension>
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed reverse host lookup (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8), address = 172.16.54.100
#0      _NativeSocket.reverseLookup.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:540:9)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).